# 'XYZ Studio' vs. 'Studio XYZ'

Tags: word-usage, word-order

Some studio names have the word studio in the front and some in the back. I wonder if there is a substantial difference in the meanings?

For example, do 'Zen Studio' and 'Studio Zen' have different meanings or give a native speaker different impressions?

Comment: The folks who pay marketing firms large sums of money to pick names like to think they give different impressions.

Comment: This is a marketing tactic, taking advantage of the difference between English and Inflected languages to make plain things sound more European.

Comment: Good question. I think the word order depends on what we 'have' as a proper noun. In hotels, I see Hotel X; in studios, I see X Studio; in cafe, I see both - X Cafe and Cafe X; in Universities, I see University ***of*** X more common.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd argue that there's no difference, from the point of view of the people hearing the company names. The people who name the company/studio may have a reason for opting for one ordering over the other but, realistically, I personally don't see a big difference.

I will argue that *switching the order* (to someone familiar with the standard order) will sound "wrong", but not because the reversed order **is** wrong... it's simply not how the company brands itself.

That being said, in English, it's significantly more common to name a company with the generic noun (studio, films, productions, etc.) last, as can bee seen on lists of companies:

- [US Recording Studios list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Recording_studios_in_the_United_States)
- [Film Production Companies list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_film_production_companies)

So, [Studio Ghibli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Studio_Ghibli) sounds fine and Ghibli Studio sounds off and [Universal Studios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Studios) is right but Studios Universal isn't recognizable but "Studio Ghibli" doesn't sound more right or wrong next to "Universal Studios".

Similar subject in the question [Why are lakes called "Lake Soandso" but seas are called "Soandso Sea"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/53268/why-are-lakes-called-lake-soandso-but-seas-are-called-soandso-sea) This addresses more the *why* of this question, whereas you're asking if there's any difference in meaning.

Answer (score 4):

By putting the noun first and the modifier second, as in

> Studio Zen

or

> Team USA

the normal word order is reversed. Thus, the whole phrase catches more attention than the regular word order of modifier, then noun, as in

> Zen Studio

or

> "USA Team"

Any time you deviate from normal word order, you are trying to call attention to something or stress something or sound a bit groovy.

In his poem ["i thank You God for most this amazing”](https://thepoetryplace.wordpress.com/2009/06/01/i-thank-you-god-for-most-this-amazing/) by e.e. cummings, the poet uses the exceptional deviation from standard word order by putting the modifier *most* in front of *this* in the first clause:

> i thank You God for **most this amazing
>
>   day**:for the leaping greenly spirits of trees
>   and a blue true dream of sky; and for everything
>   which is natural which is infinite which is yes

The normal word order would be "this most amazing day," but e.e. cummings, who was a magician with words, does something in his poem that can't really be done in prose. But it is another example of the use of non-normal word order in order to say something more powerfully than normal word order does.

While *Team USA* and *Studio Zen* may not be as magical as what e.e. cummings has written, they are still more interesting than *USA Team* and *Zen Studio*.

Comment: So how do you know that the "standard" is for the noun to be first? *USA Team* is clearly odd sounding but "Skywalker Ranch" is better than "Ranch Skywalker"... How is "Studio Ghibli" more standard than "Disney Studios"? I don't see how there's any argument that it's simply arbitrary and the decision of the company as to which sounds better.